# the modular curve of level 7 is klein quartic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Does anyone know a simple proof that the modular curve of level 7 is the Klein quartic?

I'm looking for a book that has a proof of this fact. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Eightfold-Way-Mathematical-Institute-Publications/dp/0521004195 maybe?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That was the first book I tried. It seems this fact is just roughly described in 1 or 2 lines but not a complete proof for me, since the main construction there is using triangulation, it’s hard for me to relate it to the construction of modular curves.

Comment: What level is it? $\Gamma(7)$ or $\Gamma_i(7)$ for $i=0,1$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis It should be \Gamma(7)